# Make a button with an image

Tags: java, javafx

In fact, I've managed to do that BUT i get a problem that can be easily seen in the following image:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, there's a border between the image "jugar" and the final of the button. All I want to do is to remove that, so only the background image and the button "jugar" are seen. Here's my code:

```
public final class GUI extends Application {


@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException {

    primaryStage.setTitle("CARCASSONE");

    StackPane layout = new StackPane();

    ImageView jugar = new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream("JUGAR.png")));
    final Button openButton = new Button(null, jugar);
    openButton.;
    layout.getChildren().add(openButton);

    BackgroundImage bI = new BackgroundImage(new Image(new FileInputStream("CARCASSONE.png")), null, null, null, null);
    layout.setBackground(new Background(bI));

    openButton.setOnAction(
        new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                jugarPartida(primaryStage);
            }
        });

    Scene inici = new Scene(layout, 610, 900);
    primaryStage.setScene(inici);

    primaryStage.show(); 

}
```

I must use JavaFX, so jbutton can't be used.

Any idea to solve that? Just want to remove that annoying border.

Comment: Have you tried to set the padding of the button to 0? `button.setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);`

Comment: Didn't tried but it still doesn't solve the problem at all: https://i.gyazo.com/e43faa125e6bf2dd000ec8fad8de9d3a.png I could edit the image to be a rectangle so that would work, but it has to be a way to use that image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with a transparent background is that there’s still an invisible rectangular area that responds to mouse clicks.

You can set the button’s [region shape](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#shapeProperty) and its [clip](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#clipProperty) to a shape that matches your image bounds, so the Button effectively does not exist outside of those bounds:

```
openButton.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0;");

SVGPath shape = new SVGPath();
shape.setContent("M 18 0 "
    + "H 251 C 265 0  277 7  277 25 "
    + "V 52  C 277 69 265 76 251 76 "
    + "H 18  C 12  76 0   69 0   52 "
    + "V 25  C 0   7  12  0  18  0  "
    + "z");
shape.setFill(Color.BLACK);

openButton.setShape(shape);
openButton.setClip(shape);
```

Quick SVG path tutorial:

- M means moveto (start drawing at that position)
- H means draw horizontal line to the specified X position
- V means draw vertical line to the specified Y position
- C means curveto (draw Bézier curve using specified control points; last coordinate pair is the curve’s final endpoint)
- z means close the shape

Comment: I am not very familiar with the SVG format, but wouldn't it be much simpler to just convert the image to an SVG?

Comment: @Zephyr Perhaps, but I don’t know of an easy way to convert a raster to a vector.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is apply css to set the color of openbutton to something like rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00). You can also do this directly in code.

Something like String style = "-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00);";
openButton.setStyle(style);

The last 0.0 is will make it transparent.